# high re-purpose memory count in RAMMAP

Tags: memory

I have noticed that a server I support has a lot of memory that is being re-purposed in RAMMAP. The prioproty list is 5 and this server has a lot of memory free anyway - it has 32GB of RAM and roughly about 10-15GB is in use at any one time.

Repurposed I would have thought should not be high as there is enough memory free - unless the only thing I can think of is that whatever is using this memory can only write to priority list 5? I am not a coder but is this something developers can do.

This is a Vmware VM by the way - not too sure if that matters? Historically there is not much in use as stated above.

This is from a guest server - the host is a ESX host. This is a Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 server.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This information from the guest or host operating system, you were not clear, you just mention the virtual machine.

Comment: This is from a guest Server - the host is a ESX host. This is a Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 server.

Comment: I am still not sure the reason you are concerned about Windows marking a large portion of your memory has mapped.  If the 12GB process requires additional memory, it will be provided that memory, do you still by chance have a page file configured?

Comment: It is more in regards to the repurposed column in Priority Summary tab. It is showing quite a lot of memory being re-used continuously and this is generally an indication of pages being moved aside in the standby list so that new pages can fit in - this generally is an indication of memory pressure - however, I am not sure how there is memory pressure as there is enough memory there.

Comment: this is fine. It means that Windows removed useless data from the Cache and replaced it. You should look at the non paged pool (with poolmon) and make sure that the file cache doesn't grow too much: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2014/02/27/windows-dynamic-cache-service-updated.aspx